# can't connect to apache with localhost or 127.0.0.1 on browser

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I've installed the apache2 package and have it running. When I try to test it by going to http://localhost and http://127.0.0.1, I'm greeted with "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". Running `sudo systemctl status apache2`, this is what showed up.

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /run/systemd/system/service.d
             └─zzz-lxc-service.conf
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-03-30 12:27:41 WIB; 2h 27min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
   Main PID: 5521 (apache2)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 3396)
     Memory: 14.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─5521 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─5619 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─5620 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─5621 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─5622 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─5623 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Mar 30 12:27:41 penguin systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 30 12:27:41 penguin apachectl[5520]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globall>
Mar 30 12:27:41 penguin systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 30 12:40:48 penguin systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 30 12:40:49 penguin systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I can run `ping localhost`,

```
PING localhost(localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.723 ms
```

and `ping 127.0.0.1`.

```
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.297 ms
```

I've also tried `curl http://localhost` and it shows the index.html file.

I never set up any firewall settings, in Chrome itself or in the Linux container. Can ChromeOS even do that?

Either way, from what I've looked up, if using `curl` works, then it should also work in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm so dumb it's not even funny.

Apparently, to access localhost from a Linux Container in ChromeOS, you need to access `penguin.linux.test`.